# Como obter a frequência do microfone em Hertz no Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html5, áudio, html5-audio

Estou trabalhando em um componente de uma aplicação, onde tenho que pegar a frequência de um som enviado por uma entrada de áudio (microfone).

Embora eu nunca tenha feito nada disso, dei uma pesquisada, li toda documentação do AudioContext e não identifiquei uma maneira de fazer isso a não ser APIs prontas. Ainda pesquisando eu achei um exemplo que quase de certo.

```js
var display = document.getElementById("display");

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
.then(function(stream) {
    var ctx = new AudioContext();
    /* Cria um fonte de stream */
    var source = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
    var processor = ctx.createScriptProcessor(256, 1, 1);
    source.connect(processor);
    source.connect(analyser);
    processor.connect(ctx.destination);

    processor.onaudioprocess = (data) => {
        var dataArray = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

        setInterval(() => {
            analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(dataArray);
            display.innerHTML = dataArray;
        }, 1000);
    }


})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

Se a variável `dataArray` retornasse a frequência em hertz seria o suficiente, mas aparentemente ela reage aos decibéis e não ao tom(nota) pois seus valores não são fieis aos tons das cordas dos instrumentos em hertz.

Meu projeto é fazer um afinador de guitarra/violão/baixo. Então quando a nota for tocada o código precisa dar frequência em hertz para comparar e dizer se as cordas devem ser apertadas ou afrouxadas.

Alguém sabe uma maneira de obter a frequência de uma som em HERTZ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já falei algumas vezes disso aqui, pode parecer algo bobo querer pegar frequências, mas acontece que não é, tudo vai depender de `N` fatores, o quão preciso você quer que a captura seja, as frequências capturadas serão de sons monofônicos ou não ? qual seria a frequência máxima que o seu afinador precisa capturar, são muitas variáveis, não existe uma única maneira de se fazer isso, capturar o Pitch/F0/Frequência/Período/Hz pode ser algo físico, ou seja contar quantas vezes um padrão se repete ou algo psicoacústico na qual envolve a percepção tonal do som...

Existem diferentes meios de fazer isso, tem como fazer isso no domínio do tempo (em JS existe o `getFloatTimeDomainData` para retornar os dados iniciais no domínio do tempo) aplicando técnicas de [AutoCorrelação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrela%C3%A7%C3%A3o#:%7E:text=A%20autocorrela%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20%C3%A9%20a%20correla%C3%A7%C3%A3o,impl%C3%ADcita%20pelas%20suas%20frequ%C3%AAncias%20harm%C3%B3nicas.) no sinal, existem técnicas derivadas da autocorrelação como AMDF, ASDF, YIN, etc, no domínio da Frequência também existe o equivalente a autocorrelação para encontrar a periodicidade no sinal, existem técnicas mais elaboradas que envolve encontrar o CEPSTRUM, outras técnicas envolvem somar os subharmonicos dos componentes espectrais retornados pelo FFT(Fourier),  pelo seu código acima percebi que está indo pelo domínio da frequência e tentando aplicar a [Transformada de Fourier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_de_Fourier), existe uma maneira bem simplista de encontrar frequências usando uma FFT, não é nada recomendado fazer isso em afinadores mas é uma saída inicial para seus testes e estudos, ao retornar os componentes da FFT você poderá achar a periodicidade do sinal se encontrar qual é o componente de maior amplitude, lembrando que esse método é bem rudimentar e poderá causar diversos falsos positivos .... em suma para se fazer isso você irá precisar dos seguintes dados:

```
Frequencia = Fs * i / N

Onde:

Fs = taxa de amostragem (Hz)
i = index da maior amplitude/magnitude
N = número de pontos da sua FFT
```

A taxa de amostragem padrão do [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) é de `44100Hz` então se você usar `4096` pontos em sua `FFT` vc terá uma frequência de ordem de resolução de `10,7666015625hz` ou seja, cada componente poderá estar errando aproximadamente `10Hz` então não é tão preciso assim, você poderá depois suavizar/melhorar a precisão utilizando [interpolação parabólica](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/NM/node25.html) com a ajuda dos componentes adjacentes ...

Escrevi um código básico conceitual para demonstrar como usar o web audio API para pegar os componentes espectrais, capturar a máxima amplitude do sinal e converter o índice em hertz:

hertz.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
div {
  --volume: 0%;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

div::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: var(--volume);
   background-color: green;
   transition: width 100ms linear;
}

button {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
    
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h3>ederwander hertz teste</h3>
<div id="volumeBar"></div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>

<p id="Hertz"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (async () => {
    let volumeCallback = null;
    let volumeInterval = null;
    const volumeShow = document.getElementById('volumeBar');
    const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
    const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
    var index = 0;
 
    try {
            const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: {
                echoCancellation: true
            }
        });
        const audioContext = new AudioContext();
        const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
        const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        const sampleRate = audioContext.sampleRate;
        analyser.fftSize = 4096;
        analyser.minDecibels = -127;
        analyser.maxDecibels = 0;
        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.4;
        audioSource.connect(analyser);
        var FFT = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        volumeCallback = () => {
            analyser.getByteFrequencyData(FFT);
            let dBsoma = 0;
            for(const dB of FFT)
                dBsoma += dB;
            var mediadB = dBsoma / FFT.length;
            volumeShow.style.setProperty('--volume', (mediadB * 100 / 127) + '%');
            index = FFT.indexOf(Math.max(...FFT));
            document.getElementById("Hertz").innerHTML = index*sampleRate/analyser.fftSize;
        };
  } catch(e) {
        console.error('Falha para inicializar', e);
        
   
  }
  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // update a cada 100ms
        if(volumeCallback !== null && volumeInterval === null)
        volumeInterval = setInterval(volumeCallback, 100);
  });
  stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(volumeInterval !== null) {
        clearInterval(volumeInterval);
        volumeInterval = null;
  }
  });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

teste básico com senoides puras:

Teste de 440hz com o mic ligado capturando uma senoide de `440Hz` (link youtube da senoide):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGXYFJmvIvk

print do código acima em funcionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi bem perto, capturou `441Hz`

Mais um teste com senoide, tentando capturar com o Mic uma senoide em `528Hz`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgSb8QdFU7k

print do código acima em funcionamento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também passou bem perto ...

Bom isso é o básico do básico de como se capturar freq no domínio da frequência(FFT), o código é bem simplista, se quiser algo mais preciso tenta introduzir interpolação parabólica ou usar a combinação de outros métodos descritos acima ....

PS: Para captura de áudios monofônicos que se aproximem de uma senoide pura esse método pode funcionar, talvez seja um bom início para se capturar ondas de frequências de cordas soltas (corda por corda), esse método conseguiria em suma capturar frequências que ficam acima do limite da audição humana `(22050hz)` um pouco mais que o limite de um super ouvido humano ... segue tabela das frequências por corda de uma guitarra... Uso um código mais elaborado e mais preciso do que esse exemplo para afinar meus próprios instrumentos em casa, tabela de frequência por corda solta de uma guitarra:

| Corda | Nota | Frequência | Notação formal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 (mais aguda) | Mi | 330 Hz | E4 |
| 2 | Si | 247 Hz | B3 |
| 3 | Sol | 196 Hz | G3 |
| 4 | Ré | 146 Hz | D3 |
| 5 | Lá | 110 Hz | A2 |
| 6 | Mi | 82 Hz | E2 |

Então para cada corda solta tocada você terá um parâmetro para saber se ela está perto ou distante da afinação correta !